# ¿Cómo puedo insertar saltos de linea a mi texto en PostgreSQL, para luego visualizarlo de forma ordenada en HTML?

Tags: html, nodejs, typescript, postgresql, typeorm

Explico mi problema, necesito mostrar un texto parecido a un historial clínico, al cual debo ir sumando constantemente información.
El problema es que no sé como hacer para guardar el texto con formato, para que a la hora de mostrarlo se vea correctamente.

Mi código es este:

```
findId.history = findId.history + failure

repository.save(findId)
```

pero luego se ve así:
-- INICIO DEL HISTORIAL DE LA MÁQUINA --axis roto

¿Alguna idea? Espero respuestas. Desde ya, gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Si lo estas guardando en PostgreSQl, debes hacer el `UPDATE` correspondiente agregando el caracteres de nueva linea, por ejemplo:

```
UPDATE public.tu_tabla SET 
   historial = concat(historial,CHR(13),CHR(10),'texto nuevo')
WHERE id_historial = ID;
```